# how to show the effect of the focus with the border radius..i have tried . i want it to zoom out

Tags: javascript, css, html

insert an image inside the  tag 
        and run it it may be help full to understand
         clearly

```css
.focus {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.focus:hover {
border: 70px solid #000;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="focus pic"><img src=" " ></div>
```

Comment: i want to be solved with out using the javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the default values of the element on which it should be when zooming out.

Second set transition effect to 0 in `:hover` condition.

```css
.focus {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.focus:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0s ease;
  border: 70px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="focus pic">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: you shown the same effect .. which i have shown ... when you are hovering on the image the ..i want it to be zoomed out effect

Comment: yes its quite correct but .. on hovering it should be zoomed out bro

Comment: @paone i did't get you what do you mean by "on hovering it should be zoomed out bro"

Answer (score 0):

Add a border that has no width, that way it will zoom out. Right now you remove the border if you lose focus, that does not transition.

```css
.focus {
  -webkit-transition: all 9999999s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 9999999s ease;
  -o-transition: all 9999999s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 9999999s ease;

  border: 0px solid #000;
}
.focus:hover {
  border: 70px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="focus pic"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x20" ></div>
```

Comment: @paone so you want the zoom to happen, and then stop the transition there? Without losing the effect?

Comment: @paone Look at my edit. This way the transition goes one-way, the way back takes a few days so don't worry about that :)

Comment: its just zooming i tired too